# how wso2carbon patches mechanism work?

Tags: wso2

In my environment I changed the carbon UserStoreManager class extending it and placing into the org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.2.0.jar.

This morning I got an error saying that class wasn't found.

Checking the log I found that a patch was applied and that jar overriden by a new one from the patch.

So my question is: how is this possible? what are the rules and configuration to deal with patches?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to patch some jar in a wso2 server what you have to do is create a folder named `patch<xxxx>` inside `$CARBON_HOME/repository/components/patches` where `xxxx` is the patch number. How patching in carbon works like this. When server starts if it detects patches inside patches folder and if this is the first startup or `patch0000` is not got created before then it will copy `plugins` folder to `patch0000` which is the backup of `plugins` folder and then it will copy patches in to patches in to `plugins` one by one in ascending order. Smallest patch number first and largest at last.
So make sure your patch number is the largest.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it, but my question is: does carbon create patches automaticly? who created the folders patches<xxxx>?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following documentation for more information on how to apply patch and how the patch application works in Carbon server.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process